# How to set browser page title to the one defined in post setting in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I'm modifying a joomla site template and actuality setting the page title like that:

```
<title><?php print htmlspecialchars($article->get('title'), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'); ?></title>
```

But I need it to be the one defined at the bottom of the parameter tab of the post.
How can I do ?

Comment: Please post more of the code where you set the title, what you are posting don't make sense, and is not valid php. Also explain what this means: "the one defined at the bottom of the parameter tab of the post."?

Comment: @Entretoize Your question is Unclear and light on details.  Furthermore, you can help the [joomla.se] Stack Exchange site to prosper by posting your Joomla questions there.

Comment: Sorry I forgot the code tage and stackoverflow didn't show the whole code. It's corrected.

Answer (score 0):

That works:

```
<title>
    <?php 
    $t=json_decode(print_r($article->attribs,true))->article_page_title;
    if (!$t)
        $t=$article->get('title');
    print htmlspecialchars( $t , ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'); 
    ?>
</title>
```